# How to handle array of pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Like I declared an array of pointer in a loop and use to it collect a bunch of strings by scanning, but after the loop when I want to print out the strings in the array, I found that all arrays are occupied by the same string, which is the latest one I input. The code is as following

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

char *array[3];
char content[10];
int time;
scanf("%d",&time);

for(int i=0;i<time;i++){
  scanf("%s",content);
  array[i]=content;


}

for(int j =0;j<time;j++){
  printf("%s\n",array[j]);
}

return 0;}
```

Comment: You are overwriting content.. you only store a pointer to it, not a deep copy

Comment: How may addresses does `content` have? After you assign `content` to every pointer, what address do you expect each pointer to point to?

Answer (score 1):

On every iteration input stream is copied to `content` and address of `content` is stored in `array`.
Hence `content` is overwritten again and again and address is copied to every index of `array`

```
for(int i=0;i<time;i++){
  scanf("%s",content);
  array[i]=content; //Here every array[0..time] is assigned with address of content
}
```

Which in short behaving as follows,

[image]

what you need is new storage location for every iteration which either dynamically allocated through `malloc` from heap as follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char content[10];
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char*array[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%9s", content); //ensure no more than 10 letter added includeing '/0'
        char*c = malloc(strlen(content)); 
        if(c)
        {
            strncpy(c,content,strlen(content));
            array[i] = c;
        }
        else
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }

}
```

or through VLA's as follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char*array[n];
    char content[n][10];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%9s", content[i]);
        array[i] = content[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of pointers. You still need to allocate memory for each array.

```
for(int i=0;i<time;i++){
  ret = scanf("%s",content);
  if (ret == 0) { exit(1); // handle error}
  array[i] = malloc(strlen(content)+1);
  if (array[i] == NULL) {  exit(1); // handle error}
  strcpy(array[i],content);
}
```

Remember to free at the end

```
for (int i=0; i<time; i++)
{
  free(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: nit... "You still need to allocate memory for each string and assign the beginning address to the next available pointer..." (also point out that you cannot use any input function correctly ***without checking the return***)

Comment: And even malloc can fail and indicate via return value.